# Python socket server causing Error 1006 client-side

Tags: python, sockets, server

I am currently building a small socket server in Python, and a web-based client using the WebSocket JavaScript API, and the connection keeps closing after I send the first message.
I tryed connecting to //echo.websocket.org and sending a message and there's no problem there. So as I've read that Error meant a low-level implementation error, I'm assuming that it comes from my server, may am I doing the Handshake wrong. Here is the client code:

```
function init_game(){

    socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3003');
    //socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org');
    setupSocket();
}


function setupSocket(){

    socket.onopen = function(){
        console.log('Connection open !');

        var msg = {cmd: 'hello', params: {}};
        var data = JSON.stringify(msg);
        console.log('Sending : ' + data);
        socket.send(data);
    };

    socket.onmessage = function(e){

        var data = e.data;
        console.log('Received : ' + data);
        handle(data);
    };

    socket.onerror = function(e){
        console.log('ERROR : ' + e.code + " - " + e.reason);
    };

    socket.onclose = function(e){
        console.log('CONNECTION CLOSED : ' + e.code + " - " + e.reason);
    }
}

function handle(data){
    //doing stuff
}

window.onload = init_game;
```

And here the server code:

```
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, conn, id, q):

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.conn_ = conn
        self.id_ = id
        self.name_ = ''
        self.q_ = q
        self.handshaken_ = True
        self.encoded_ = False


    # Main loop
    def run(self):

        raw_data = self.conn_.recv(1024)

        if raw_data[:3] == 'GET':
            self.handshaken_ = False
            self.handshake(raw_data)

        while True:

            raw_data = self.conn_.recv(1024)

            if len(raw_data) == 0:
                continue

            if self.handshaken_:                

                if self.encoded_:
                    raw_data = self.decode(raw_data).decode('utf-8')

                try:

                    data = json.loads(raw_data)
                    cmd = data['cmd']
                    params = data['params'] 
                    self.handle(cmd, params)

                except ValueError, e:
                    print 'Data received was not JSON'

            else:
                print 'Received something but Handshake is not done yet... Something is going wrong.'


    # Decode encoded message received frmo the client
    def decode(self, data):

        frame = bytearray(data)

        length = frame[1] & 127

        indexFirstMask = 2
        if length == 126:
            indexFirstMask = 4
        elif length == 127:
            indexFirstMask = 10

        indexFirstDataByte = indexFirstMask + 4
        mask = frame[indexFirstMask:indexFirstDataByte]

        i = indexFirstDataByte
        j = 0
        decoded = []
        while i < len(frame):
            decoded.append(frame[i] ^ mask[j%4])
            i += 1
            j += 1

        return "".join(chr(byte) for byte in decoded)


    # Performs handshake protocole in case it's needed
    def handshake(self, get):

        websocket_answer = (
            'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
            'Upgrade: websocket',
            'Connection: Upgrade',
            'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key}\r\n\r\n',
        )
        GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"

        raw_key = re.search('Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r]+', get)

        if raw_key != None:

            # Create Handshake answer...
            key = raw_key.groups()[0].strip()
            handshake_key = b64encode(sha1(key + GUID).digest())
            handshake = '\r\n'.join(websocket_answer).format(key=handshake_key)

            # And send it to the client
            self.conn_.send(handshake)
            self.handshaken_ = True
            self.encoded_ = True

        else:
            print 'No key found during Handshake.'
            self.disconnect()


    # Handle JSON commands send by the client
    def handle(self, cmd, params):
        # doing stuff

    def disconnect(self):
        print 'Disconnecting.'
        pass


class MainServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.HOST = ''
        self.PORT = 3003
        self.socket_ = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            self.socket_.bind((self.HOST, self.PORT))
        except socket.error as msg:
            print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
            sys.exit()

        self.clients_ = {1: Player(1), 2: Player(2)}
        self.q_ = Queue()

    def run(self):

        self.socket_.listen(10)

        nb_player = 0
        new_id = 1
        while nb_player < 2:
            conn, addr = self.socket_.accept()
            print 'A new player connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])
            self.clients_[new_id].conn = conn
            th = ClientThread(conn, new_id, self.q_)
            th.start()
            new_id += 1
            nb_player += 1

        while True:
            data = self.q_.get(block=True)
            self.handle(data['cmd'], data['params'])

    def handle(self, cmd, params):
        # doing stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':

    serv = MainServer()
    serv.start()
```

Please tell me if you need any other information.
Thanks !
Robin

Comment: Socket Error are usually 1006x (x is a decimal digit). Did you miss a digit?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the connection is closing automatically, with a code 1006 (in socket.onclose, event.code). socket.onerror is also called though, but event.code or event.reason are both undefined.

Comment: Alright so I think I figured what caused the error, it was probably a security error or something, because I didn't encode the data before sending it server-side.
But now that I do (using the encoding code found here: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~goldsd/docs/spring2012-csci4220/websocket-py.txt ), when I send the message from the server to the client, socket.onmessage is not called...

Comment: And after a few second have this message : "The connection with xs://IP:PORT/ has been interrupt during the loading of the page."